# Different version of android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat?

Tags: java, android

This might be a setup question for android. I am trying to use some code that use `ViewCompat` from `android.support.v4.view`.

In this class (and from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html), it clearly has methods like `setPivotX`, `setTranslationY`, but in my project it said that there is not such method for `ViewCompat` even though I did have import `android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat` on the top successfully.

My `android-support-v4.jar` is in `android-support-v7-appcompat`.  I tried to download `android-support-v4.jar` from other places and still no such methods (viewed all methods in eclipse).  I bumped my `minsdk` version to 11 and still no help.

Any hint/help on where I might have the setup in the wrong way?  It seems that the `ViewCompat` that I have is different from the android documentation.

Comment: Where have you put your `.jar` file?

Comment: My project use android-support-v7-appcompat as reference library. The android-support-v4.jar is in android-support-v7-appcompat/libs

Comment: put it in the `project/app/libs` folder and sync again

Comment: What version of support v7 are you using (and thus what version of v4)? The methods you're referring to were introduced to support animations for the 'new' `RecyclerView` widget. The actual commit goes back [more than a year](http://goo.gl/RJMBpn), but I suppose they weren't available until revision 21 of the support v4 library (October 2014). It might be worth inspecting the [Dependency Tree](http://goo.gl/1ebzau) in Eclipse to determine which library resolves to which support lib version.

Comment: Ah, I did android-support-v7-appcompat->android tools->add support library-> and did a installation for android support library 21.0.3, and now all methods are supported as the jar apparently got updated.   Thanks so much for the help.